# Como puedo sacar un objeto dentro de otro objeto en php

Tags: javascript, php, html, cakephp

Hola amigos tengo este resultado
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como ven en la columna Rol hay un objeto dentro de objetos entonces lo que yo quiero es selecionar ese objeto que duce Roles:{"nombre"} o sea quiero sacar la palabra profesor

Este es mi codigo

```
 <?php  foreach ($data as $d): ?>
                
                <tr>
                <td><?= h($d->id) ?></td>
                <td><?= h($d->nombres) ?></td>
                <td><?= h($d->apellidos) ?></td>
                <td><?= h($d->rut) ?></td>
                <td><?= h($d->dv) ?></td>
                <td><?= h($d) ?></td>
                
                </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
```

imagine hacer esto $d->_matchingData->Roles->nombre Pero esto no funciono

Comment: Que error te sale?

Comment: Prueba lo siguiente   $d["_matchingData"]["Roles"]["nombre"];

Comment: la solucion era esta gracias $d["_matchingData"]["Roles"]["nombre"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si no estoy incorrecto eso es un diccionario, por lo tanto tienes que acceder al dato con la clave, prueba algo asi:

```
$d["_matchingData"]["Roles"]["nombre"];
```

ya que no estas intentando acceder a un objeto, si no a un diccionario